# How can I replace replace \" with '

Tags: python, json, string, replace, html-escape-characters

I have the following content:

```
{

"z":"[{\"ItemId\":\"1234\",\"a\":\"1234\",\"b\":\"4567\",\"c\":\"d\"}]"

}
```

This is a part of the json response I get from a certain API. I need to replace the `\"`s with `'`s. Unfortunately, that's where I got stuck!

Most of the answers I get are simply replacing the `\` with `""` or `" "` so that did not help me. So my question are the following:

How can I replace the `\"` with `'`:

1. in a file where I copy-pasted the content?
2. if I receive this as a response to a certain API call?

I tried the following to replace the content in a file but I am clearly only replacing the `"`s with `'`:

```
  with open(file, "r") as f:
    content = f.read()
    new_content = content.replace("\"", "'")
    with open(file, "w") as new_file:
        new_file.write(new_content)
```

Comment: Eh? `'`s aren't valid in JSON.

Comment: Do you really want your file to contain a Python `repr()` of the object, instead of a JSON representation? There are easier ways to do that.

Comment: This depends on what exactly the JSON contains. If the `\"` in the JSON is meant to represent just the quote character, which is more likely, then printing it as `\"` is something python might do automatically, and replacing it would just be doing `content.replace('"', "'")` (using the 'other' quotation mark). On the other hand, if it's actually literally two characters, then you'd want to replace the combination of backslash and quote by writing a literal backslash and quote `'\\"'`

Comment: `myobject["z"] = json.loads(myobject["z"])` would put a _literal object_ in place of your key; `myobject["z"] = repr(json.loads(myobject["z"]))` would replace the JSON with a Python repr, which is more in line with what you're literally asking for.

Comment: Okay, the confirmation that that's what you're looking for means I should be able to add an answer to that effect...

Comment: I must clarify a bit: the json response contains values like true, false and null, which was really giving me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is transform each value from a JSON string to a Python repr() string, while keeping the wrapper format as JSON, that might look like:

```
with open(filename, "r") as old_file:
  old_content = json.load(old_file)
  new_content = {k: repr(json.loads(v)) for k, v in old_content.items()}
  with open(filename, "w") as new_file:
    json.dump(new_content, new_file)
```

If your old file contains:

```json
{"z":"[{\"ItemId\":\"1234\",\"a\":\"1234\",\"b\":\"4567\",\"c\":\"d\"}]"}
```

...the new file will contain:

```json
{"z": "[{'ItemId': '1234', 'a': '1234', 'b': '4567', 'c': 'd'}]"}
```

Note that in this new file, the inner fields are now in Python format, not JSON format; they can no longer be parsed by JSON parsers. Usually, I would suggest doing something different instead, as in:

```
with open(filename, "r") as old_file:
  old_content = json.load(old_file)
  new_content = {k: json.loads(v) for k, v in old_content.items()}
  with open(filename, "w") as new_file:
    json.dump(new_content, new_file)
```

...which would yield an output file with:

```json
{"z": [{"ItemId": "1234", "a": "1234", "b": "4567", "c": "d"}]}
```

...which is both easy-to-read and easy to process with standard JSON-centric tools (`jq`, etc).

Comment: Hi @Charles Duffy. This was me being an idiot and unaware of the json module. Thanks for nudging me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Using `json` module, you can dumps the data then loads it using the following:

```py
import json

data = {

    "z": "[{\"ItemId\":\"1234\",\"a\":\"1234\",\"b\":\"4567\",\"c\":\"d\"}]"

}


g = json.dumps(data)

c = json.loads(data)

print(c)

print(str(c).replace("\"","'"))
```

Output:

```
{'z': '[{"ItemId":"1234","a":"1234","b":"4567","c":"d"}]'}

{'z': '[{'ItemId':'1234','a':'1234','b':'4567','c':'d'}]'}
```

Comment: AFAICT, the OP is asking for `{"z": "[{'ItemID':'1234','a':'1234','b':'4567','c':'d'}]"}` -- replacing the quotes _inside the value_ while keeping the wrapping format JSON.

Comment: Hmm, i think that am somehow lost within the comments